# Save a CaptureVisibleTab image to a temp file to send through Node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture a visible tab using a chrome extension. I've managed to get the image to display in another Tab to check its working. But I actually want the image to be taken, save as a PNG in a temp file on the users computer. Then eventually be sent to a server but thats a different problem. Apologies if the formatting is poor I'm learning.

```
var id = 100;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(screenshotUrl) {
    var viewTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('../HTML/InfoPullHTML.html?id=' + id++)
    var targetId = null;

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {

      if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete")
        return;
      // alert('test2');

      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
      // alert('test3');

      var views = chrome.extension.getViews(); 
      // alert('test4');
      for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        var view = views[i];
        // alert('test' + (i + 5));
        if (view.location.href == viewTabUrl) {
          view.setScreenshotUrl(screenshotUrl);
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    // alert('AfterForLoop');

    chrome.tabs.create({url: viewTabUrl}, function(tab) {
      targetId = tab.id;
    });
  });
});
```

Image gets taken. Save image as PNG and save in a temp file on the users computer.

Right now my only result really is the image gets taken then is displayed in a new tab. I'm a beginner to coding and I haven't got the slightest clue on how to move forwards with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="../JavaScript/BrowserInfoJS.js"></script>
<script src="../JavaScript/ScreenshotTargetJS.js"></script>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Image here:
  <p>
    <img id="target" src="../images/white.png">
  <p>
    End image
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page the image is displayed on once the extension is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There are [storage APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage) you can use. For saving a file, use [Filesystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem).

But since it seems that you want to save the file only to upload it later, it would be simpler to deal with the local storage API:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({format:"png"}, src=>{
    //
    chrome.storage.local.get({"captured": []}, s=>{
            //
            s.captured.push(src);
            chrome.storage.local.set({"captured": s.captured});
        });
});
```

Be sure to declare the `unlimitedStorage` permission if you're storing large images, or more than one image at a time.

Comment: If I use local storage will it not be saved on the users computer until they delete it? I'm working on a mock project for work and the client (user) cannot have any of the files saved onto their computer.

Comment: @CalciumCal The user doesn't have direct access to local storage data. It will persist until the extension deletes it.

Comment: Oh I actually had no idea. I was under the impression local storage was essentially them saving it to their personal directories but I actually think that is what I'm looking for if I can find a way to save it to the local system then delete it after it's finished. Thank you!